# Some basic questions about debugging core files C++/linux?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks, gdb, coredump

Debugging files of C++ applications/linux have always been a mystery to me and some basic understanding is lacking.

(1) Do we need to necessarily compile applications with -g flag without which core files are unable to give any useful information whatsoever? But I see that even when we don't compile with -g flag, core files are generated -- so they must be serving some purpose apart from occupying space on disk.

Wikipedia says : "In computing, a core dump, memory dump, or storage dump consists of the recorded state of the working memory of a computer program at a specific time, generally when the program has terminated abnormally (crashed)".

This should mean that irrespective of if we compiled with -g flag, we still have state. and if we have stack track, we should still be able to know what function caused the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-g` option has nothing to do with the core files, but with putting debug information in the *program*. That is, the generated executable file will contain all symbols (e.g. function and variable names) as well as line number information (so you can find out which line a crash occurs in).

The actual core dump only contains a memory dump. Yes you can, together with the program, get a stack trace, but unless the program has debug information you can not see function names or line numbers, only their addresses.

Comment: That depends.  If you haven't stripped the executable, public symbols (those with external linkage in C++) should still be available.

Answer (score 1):

> *so they must be serving some purpose apart from occupying space on disk*

You can limit size of core files with `ulimit -c $limit` command and your core files won't occupy your disk space.

And, as Joachim already said `-g` option just includes debug symbols and checks to your program.